# Python module manipulation with other modules

Tags: python, module, interaction

I was fooling around with python modules today and i found something interesting; Suppose you have a module like this:

```
# mymodule

value = "default"

def setVal(new):
    value = new

def getVal():
    return value
```

now, you have another module that imports mymodule. when you run the module in python shell, this happens:

```
>>> moduleC.setC("newvalue")
>>> moduleC.getC()
'default'
>>> moduleC.Cval = "new value"
>>> moduleC.getC()
'new value'
```

Why does setting the value of the variable in a module using a function not work, but assigning it using "=" does?

Comment: @TerryJanReedy makes a good point in an answer below - in Python, neither `setVal()` nor `getVal()` are necessary. If value is declared at the module level, you can just access it with `MyModule.value`, and change it as you see fit. Python is not Java :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you setVal, `value` is local to the function, and 'disappears' when the function returns.  To make it global to the module, you must declare it so.  This will do as you hoped, even though it is unnecessary (as is getVal()).

```
def setVal(new):
    global value
    value = new
```

Answer (score 0):

you can run the code below and see whatś happening

```
value = 123

def setVal(new):
    value = new
    print globals()
    print locals()

def getVal():
    return value


setVal(22222)
print getVal()
```

and then:

```
value = 123

def setVal(new):
    global value
    value = new
    print globals()
    print locals()

def getVal():
    return value


setVal(22222)
print getVal()
```

EDIT: If you want to use the global variable `value` in your method,just declare  what you want to use is just the global one ,not a newly created  one. If not,a local variable named value will be created and then there are two variables named `value` - the global one(123) and the local one(equal to the parameter new).